# Correct format for multiline '--data' in curl query to graphql endpoint?

Tags: json, curl, graphql

I'm passing "--data" via curl to a GraphqQL API endpoint.

I want to be able to pass the data in 'prettified' form, e.g. as in GraphiQL browser,

```
{
  alpha {
    param1
    param2
  }
}
```

Atm, my formatting *inside* the data -- namely, re: line returns -- isn't handled properly.

This single-line-string form works,

```
curl \
 -H 'content-type: application/json' \
 -X POST /path/to/graphql/api/endpoint \
 --data '{ "query":
           "query { alpha {param1, param2} } "
         }'
```

This 'prettified' version does not

```
curl \
 -H 'content-type: application/json' \
 -X POST /path/to/graphql/api/endpoint \
 --data '{ "query":
           "query {
              alpha {
                param1
                param2
              }
            } "
         }'
```

What's the right syntax for passing the 2nd form?

I'm guessing some combination of quoting/escaping?

Answer (score 4):

Newlines just aren't allowed inside JSON strings.  (See [RFC 8259 §7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7), which states that control characters must be escaped.)  You can turn a newline into `\n`, but that gets a little unwieldy:

```sh
curl \
 -H 'content-type: application/json' \
 -X POST /path/to/graphql/api/endpoint \
 --data '{ "query":
           "query {\n  alpha {\n    param1\n    param2\n  }\n} "
         }'
```

Since the JSON queries are pretty well-structured, it seems to work better to use a dedicated tool for submitting GraphQL queries: the standalone version of [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) is an okay default, or if you have a favorite scripting language with a reasonable HTTP client it's easy enough to write something with that.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of this:

```
QUERY='{ "query":
           "query {
              alpha {
                param1
                param2
              }
            } "
         }'
curl \
 -H 'content-type: application/json' \
 -X POST /path/to/graphql/api/endpoint \
 --data "$(echo $QUERY)"
```

Comment: This is what I had to do: `--data "${QUERY//$'\n'/}"`. It may not work in all cases but for my simple use-case it worked.

Comment: The answer doesn't work 1:1 in a bash shell, but the previous comment fixes this